# How to add Selenium Firefox profile in Work Space permanent

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox-addon

I have created Firefox profile for webDriver.

Code is below for the created profile:

```
    ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
    FirefoxProfile myProfile = profile.getProfile("Selenium");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(myProfile);
```

Where "Selenium" is profile name. It is working fine in my machine.
Now, I want to deploy this project to some one else. But he has not set the preferences in firefox profile as same as mine. So, he cant use the script.

How can i add this firefox profile in my framework/project, so if i give the same framework to some else, he can use the same functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to backup your profile as described in this [tutorial](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/back-and-restore-information-firefox-profiles) from Mozilla. Than make that profile part of you project (so drop it somewhere into `src/test/resources`) and just do

```
File profileDir = new File(profileLocation);
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(profileDir);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Or alternatively you can create your own inside Java code, it depends how much settings your profile has.

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("general.useragent.override", "some UA string");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```